# Восстановление Ubuntu После неправильной установки драйвера Nvidia

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia, видеодрайвера

Решил установить видео драйвер Nvidia на Ubuntu, вот что и как делал:

1) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>

2) ввел логин и пароль

3) `sudo service lightdm stop`

4) `sudo init 3`

5) `cd путь к файлу драйвера`

6) `sudo sh ./NVID*`

После этого пошла установка драйвера, во время которой вылезло окошко что-то типа "установка может зафейлится, продолжить?", я по дурости кликнул да и установка продолжилась.

После установки драйвера ввел команду `sudo service lightdm start`, после этого операционка так и не завелась. Выключал компьютер удерживая кнопку выключения. Каждый раз при включении зависает на логотипе убунту.

Как пробовал решить проблему:

По инструкции из [ответа на похожий вопрос](https://askubuntu.com/a/218095/525610) следовал по всем шагам:

1) при включении в grub выбрал пункт `ubuntu, whith Linux X.X.X-XX-generic (recovery mode)`

[image]

2) Из меню выбрал пункт `failsafeX`

[image]

3) Появляется окошко

[image]

4) Нажимаю ок, появляется следующее окно

[image]

В нем перепробовал все варианты, кликал на все по очереди как истаричка, ничего не помогло.

5) На этом моменте пробовал нажать <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>, но вместо ввода логина и ароля вижу вот это:

[image]

Тоже самое, но лучше видно текст:

[image]

Тут не получается ввести команды, просто переходит на новую строку по нажатию на <kbd>Enter</kbd>

**Вопрос:** Что мне сделать, чтоб хотя бы вернуться к состоянию когда работало со старым драйвером? (бекапов, к сожалению, нет никаких) Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: sudo aptitude -y install nvidia-current что-нибудь даёт? P.S. Заканчивай тянуть виндовые привычки в *nix. Тут это редко работает хорошо.

Comment: Я в терминал не могу команды вводить, они вводятся как текст и при нажатии на энтер просто на новую строку переходит курсор. А с виндовыми привычками - да, тут мой косяк, на линуксе 4 день сижу, сложно сходу перестроится.

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+F1,2,3,4,5,6 - хоть на каком-нить из них есть просто обычное приглашение на ввод логина?

Comment: Нет, либо ничего не происходит, либо открывается как на последней картинке из поста

Comment: Тогда следующий вопрос: ты хочешь решить эту проблему из академического интереса или хочешь, чтобы просто работало?

Comment: *2) Из меню выбрал пункт failsafeX* — выберите пункт «запустить shell». но раз вы всего 4 дня как осваиваете новое, вам проще будет переустановить систему. по-началу это нормальное явление.

Comment: Хочу чтобы работало, так как решил пересесть с винды на убунту (раньше возможность не было, так как разрабатывал программы на флеше, и там есть ограничения от адоба, а сейчас перехожу на разработку под андроид и винда по сути не нужна). А полез устанавливать дрова, так как лаги были при прокрутке даже текста.

Comment: Лучше тогда снеси и поставь заново. /home можно не затирать, если он был на отдельном разделе.

Comment: Переустанавливать не хотелось бы, только настроил среду разработки и тому подобное..)

Comment: Тогда загрузись с livecd и перенеси куда-нибудь всю папку /home/user. В новую систему верни всё обычным переносом.

Comment: Спасибо! Буду пробовать!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запустите из GRUB **root** и введите команду `sudo apt remove nvidia-*`. Команда удалит все драйвера nvidia и убунту запустится с помощью интегрированного графического адаптера. После запуска у вас будет возможность переустановить драйвера другими методами