# Зависает "Подготовка к установке Ubuntu"

Tags: ubuntu

На компьютере уже стоит винда 8 и убунту, но последняя в не рабочем состоянии (подробности о неработоспособности можно посмотреть в моем [прошлом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/509853/205673)), загрузился с флешки, копировал `/home` директорию на раздел с данными, пробую переустановить убунту, но она зависает на моменте "Подготовка к установке Ubuntu", так же всплывает непонятный алерт.

[image]

Что не так? Как это пофиксить?

Так же интересует не убьется ли уже существующий grub, в котором есть пункт загрузки винды при переустановке убунты?

**P.S.** С ubuntu ковыряюсь 4 день, ответ хотелось бы получить максимально развернутый. Если надо куда-то залезть и посмотреть какие-то логи, пожалуйста, напишите как залезть и т.п. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: версия бунты? Попробуй выставить английский на начальном этапе установки, может текст ошибки будет осмысленный.

Comment: Попробуй netboot-версию. http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/mini.iso

Comment: Проверь память (`memtest` в grub, достаточно минут 20 чтобы поработал, еслли ошибок не будет, можно выходить, не дожидаться завершения) и файловый системы (`fsck` в recovery mode). До этого установщик работал, а сейчас перестал?

Comment: Спасибо, попробую. Да, установщик работал

Comment: Вопрос немного не по сабжу. Я так понимаю убунта параллельно поставлена с виндой? Если ли какие-то проблемы после установки, а то где-то давно читал, что там что-то связанное с uefi может мешать загрузке/работе убунты..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуй перезаписать установочную флешку.  [UNetbootin](https://sourceforge.net/projects/unetbootin/?source=typ_redirect) в помощь!

Comment: Помогло, видимо сбилось что-то на флешке