# Как исправить ошибку при установке ubuntu на raid0?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

При установке Ubuntu вылезло такое непонятное окно. При нажатии ОК или на крестик ничего не происходит.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скорее всего проблема с установочным образом (носителем).

Comment: Качал с официального сайта, чистый образ.Устанавливаю с флешки.
Собственно, что делать дальше? Если убью процесс, ничего не поломается?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/509904/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BA-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B5-ubuntu подобная проблема

Comment: Смотря что на Вашем компьютере находится, а так просто не будет загружаться компьютер скорее всего.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую. Подскажите, как корректно выйти из процесса установки? Т.к. это окно появилось после разметки дисков, боюсь чтобы ничего не повредилось

Comment: Кнопка "Выкл" на компьютере. А так любое "прерывание" установки будет некорректным.

Comment: вполне возможно, что «вопросы» представляют собой какой-то текст в неправильной кодировке. если такое повторяется неоднократно, имеет смысл запустить установку, выбрав английский язык интерфейса.

Answer (score 1):

Если рэйд аппаратный то возможно драйвер не включен в ядро.

Если Вы делаете программный рейд то нужно пробовать утилиту mdadm  http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_raid

`mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=stripe --raid-devices=2 /dev/sdb6 /dev/sdc5`

https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RAID_setup#RAID-0

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте устанавливать не с загруженного лайф диска, а  выберите вариант загрузки или графический режим или псевдо графический

Касательно, записи установочной флешки, делаю так 
правда только под Linux,ом. 
Выясняем как определилась флешка в системе fdisk -l,
выяснили что флешка это /dev/sdb или /dev/sdс или ещё как то ...
потом
dd if=ubuntu.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=512k

Записываю флешку так постоянна ubuntu или debian, ни каких проблем

Comment: *`dd if=ubuntu.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=512k`* — слишком сложно, длинно, и просто излишне. в *gnu/linux* отлично работает элементарное копирование: `cp ubuntu.iso /dev/sdb`

Comment: Пробовал и так, и этак. И язык на английский менял, вопросительные знаки пропадут. Все равно одно и тоже.
Правда окно уже стало закрываться, но после закрытия перекидывает обратно на разметку дисков.
Видимо все из-за того что ubuntu не умеет ставится на raid0. Он видит все 2 диска с разделами, а не как windows - один целый диск.